# Is there a way that we can start BLE advertising in "Extended Mode" (LE CODED PHY) in Android App?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am BLE advertising on my android app in Normal mode. Now, i am required to advertise in `extended mode` `(LE CODED PHY)`. Can someone please help me out here as how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

So Basically, we can change it before we're advertising.

And we can use `AdvertisingSetParameters` for that. Like in the example below:

```js
AdvertisingSetParameters advertisingSetParameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
  .setLegacyMode(false).setPrimaryPhy(PHY_LE_CODED).setPrimaryPhy(PHY_LE_CODED).build();
```